# Qwt date-time axis

Tags: qt, datetime, qwt

I inherit class from QwtScaleDraw to show date-time axis:

```
class TimeScaleDraw: public QwtScaleDraw {
public:
TimeScaleDraw(const QDateTime &base) : baseDateTime(base) {
  setLabelRotation(0);
  setLabelAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
  setSpacing(20);
}
virtual QwtText label(double v) const {
  QDateTime dateTime;
  dateTime = dateTime.fromTime_t(v);
  return dateTime.toString("yyyy.MM.dd\nhh:mm:ss");
}
private:
QDateTime baseDateTime;
};
```

In main file I use it as:

```
funPlot->setAxisScaleDraw(QwtPlot::xBottom, new TimeScaleDraw(QDateTime::currentDateTime()));
```

I want to see the current date-time when I run the app. Is it possible? Now it displays as 1970.01.00 00:00:00 with an appropriate scale.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print out what you are passing as `double v`, it probably just can't get converted to `QDateTime`. You need to add these seconds to `baseDateTime`.

```
virtual QwtText label(double v) const {
  QDateTime dateTime = baseDateTime.addSecs(v);
  return dateTime.toString("yyyy.MM.dd\nhh:mm:ss");
}
```